# How do I clone a single drive onto a new RAID 1 array?

Tags: fedora, grub2, raid, cloning

Here's a little background on the situation at hand. I have a DELL Precision T7600 at work that I'm responsible for maintaining, which just lost a hard-drive, thankfully just the /home directory was on it, and has now been recovered. Now I've been tasked with making a RAID 1 of the OS drive so that our downtime is to a minimum.

I've read about hard-drive cloning, on the Arch-Linux wiki, and am currently following these [two](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-10.04) [guides](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/238/Migrating_To_RAID1_Mirror_on_Sarge), leaning on the first for the grub2 configuration, but I could not wrap my head around the process. Perhaps I'm making this too complex and it is a simple `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/md126` command. Is `dd`ing to an array from a device file even possible or recommended? I'm not sure what's best practice here.

I tried `dd`ing to the /dev/md0 device, but it was a tiny bit smaller, than the original, so I got an error from `dd` about not being able to copy to `/dev/md0`. Also, I tried to boot off of this array, but ran into `error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.` and was put into a `grub rescue>`, which I don't know what to do with. So I tried to mount the array in order to do a `grub-install` on it, but was met with failure, as `mount` told me: `unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'`

I ran the following command to clone my OS drive to the two blank drives:

`sudo pv /dev/sdc | tee >(dd of=/dev/sda) >(dd of=/dev/sdb) | dd of=/dev/null`

This cloned my OS drive successfully, without grub errors like the 1st attempt. Grub loaded, but would not boot the OS, and I was thrown into dracut emergency mode. I got out of this by issuing the following commands from my LiveUSB `sfdisk -d /dev/sdc | sfdisk /dev/sda` and ditto for `sdb`.

Fedora loaded this time, but I was thrown into emergency mode, which is caused, at least in my case, as I've dealt with it before, by inexistant `/etc/fstab` entries. So I pruned the fstab to only mount the `/` partition.

Now I ran:

`sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb`

from my Live USB stick, to create the array, but after doing this the drives were still not bootable. So I had to re `dd` the `sdc2` and `sdc3` partitions, to their respective `sdb` partitions. And I'm back at square one.

This time I decided to create 3 separate RAID partitions. And created a file called `/etc/grub.d/09_raid1_setup`:

```
menuentry 'Fedora RAID 1' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    insmod mdraid1x
    set root='(md/2)'
    search --no-floppy --set=root /dev/md2 
    linux /vmlinuz-3.18.9-100.fc20.x86_64 root=/dev/md3 ro
    initrd /initramfs-3.18.9-100.fc20.x86_64.img
}
```

Then I recreated the new `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and ran `dracut -f /boot/initramfs-currentimage` to update the initramfs.

I also made the mistake of not changing the partition table of `sdb` to match that of `sda`, which looks like:

```
Part. #     Size        Partition Type            Partition Name
----------------------------------------------------------------
         1007.0 KiB  free space
1        1024.0 KiB  BIOS boot partition
2        500.0 MiB   Linux RAID
3        97.7 GiB    Linux RAID
4        2.6 TiB     Linux RAID
         455.5 KiB   free space
```

until after I had created the initramfs image and updated `grub.cfg`.

The output of lsblk now looks like the following:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0     1M  0 part  
├─sda2    8:2    0   500M  0 part  
├─sda3    8:3    0  97.7G  0 part  /
└─sda4    8:4    0   2.6T  0 part  
sdb       8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0     1M  0 part  
├─sdb2    8:18   0   500M  0 part  
│ └─md2   9:2    0 499.7M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdb3    8:19   0  97.7G  0 part  
│ └─md3   9:3    0  97.6G  0 raid1 
└─sdb4    8:20   0   2.6T  0 part  
  └─md4   9:4    0   2.6T  0 raid1 
sdc       8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk  /home
```

And `/etc/fstab` is:

```
/dev/md3 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
/dev/md2 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=f9fba42e-80f4-41b1-b309-88b22f642907 /home                 ext4    defaults        1 2
```

After some [research](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-10.04-p2), [reading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526747/setting-up-raid-1-on-14-04-with-an-existing-drive), and [general](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/238/Migrating_To_RAID1_Mirror_on_Sarge) [googling](https://ritter.vg/blog-grub2_raid_boot.html), I still can't find any answers which fit my situation.

Thank you for your time and input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure there is at least 1mb or so of free space at the end of the existing disk.  Resize the last partition if need be.  Then simply create the raid array out of both disks ( list the original disk first ).  Be sure to use the `-e 1.0` switch to `mdadm` to make sure it places the raid metadata in the end of the disk.  It will automatically start copying the contents of the original drive to the new drive.  You will need to do all of this while booted from some other drive, or at least with all filesystems mounted read only.  Reboot when done with this, then reinstall grub.  If your /etc/fstab is using UUIDs that is all you need to do; if not, you will need to make sure it is set to point to /dev/mdXpY instead of /dev/sdapY.

Comment: First of all thanks for the feedback. I will try this as soon as I get into work tomorrow. So let me get this straight, you said from a LiveUSB just run `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb -e 1.0` and it will not overwrite my existing partition table? So there is no need to manually copy `/` or `/boot` from `sda` to `sdb`? Also will the reboot use the existing bootloader to boot from `sda2` and then allow me to run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` once booted into Fedora? Will I have to remake the initramfs?

Comment: Correct; `mdadm` will just copy the entire drive, minus its little metadata it puts at the end, over to the new drive.  If you then mount the raid, chroot into it, and reinstall grub, it will be configured to boot from the array instead of an individual drive.

Comment: I ran `mdadm` just like I mentioned above, it created the array but I cannot mount it thus I cannot `chroot` into it. `sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/md0` gives `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`. This is all from the LiveUSB. Perhaps if I reboot into the OS then I don't need to `chroot` and I should be able to `mount`?

Comment: Seems like after rebooting, without waiting for the array to completely rebuild, the array is not visible under `lsblk`. Perhaps I should wait for it to rebuild b/c the superblock is at the end? And then try to mount?

Comment: @rivanov, your disk contains partitions, so you need to mount a partition in the array, not the whole array as if it were just one filesystem.

Comment: I'm actually considering doing something similar to [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-10.04-p2) method. Only that I will 1) create a degrated array using your idea with `-e 1.0` 2) cp the `/boot` and `/` partitions over to the mirrored `sdb` disk 3) Do what you suggested and `chroot` into the array and ... IDK what else yet, but I'll keep you posted on progress. Wish me luck!

Comment: Well this method does not make any partitions, that would involve the use of something like `parted`, which would destroy data, which is not a problem with me, in this specific case; the method just makes `/dev/md0`, if I understand correctly, and won't let me mount it until I use `mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0`, which I don't want to do since it will nuke my data.

Comment: @rivanov, you alredy *have* partitions on the disk.  After you create the raid array out of the disk, the array will then have those partitions.

Comment: I understand this. `lsblk` does show the partitions as being there. Unfortunately this method does not work because I cannot mount the array after it was created.

Comment: @rivanov, again, you don't mount the array, you mount a *partition* on the array.  That is, you mount /dev/md0p1 ( assuming partition 1 ), not /dev/md0.

Comment: That device does not exist under `/dev`. Am I understanding incorrectly here?

Comment: @rivanov, it should... does `parted /dev/md0 print` show a partition table?

Comment: Thanks so much for referring me to `parted`. What I had to do to get the partition table to print, and yes, now `dev/md0p1` does exist, was to run `sudo gdisk /dev/md0`, and repair the damaged GPT from the main header. That was using `r` for recovery mode, then `d` to repair the main backup header from the main header. Now what should I do? I just `chroot`ed into the now mounted `md0p2`(`/boot`) and `md0p3` (`/`), and ran `grub2-mkconfig` after having to add `/usr/sbin` to the path. Do I do a `grub-install /dev/sda` or `grub-install /dev/md0p1`?

Comment: One more question, I was able to boot after running `grub2-install /dev/sda`, but now none of the partitions for `sda` come up once booted from itself, only the `sdb` partitions are displayed by `lsblk`. Am I acutally booted off of RAID? Do I have to wait for the array to rebuild before booting?

Comment: I'm afraid I've run into an insurmountable problem. `grub-install /dev/md0` [fails](http://askubuntu.com/questions/468466/why-this-occurs-error-diskfilter-writes-are-not-supported), and `grub-install /dev/sda` will wipe the partition table! Unfortunately I've run out of time on this issue, as the system needs to be operational. I will settle cloning the disk manually every month, for a sort of ghetto RAID. Thanks for all your time and effort. I know it's really disappointing that we've not figured it out, but I just cannot continue.

Comment: @rivanov, maybe redhat is different.  On Ubuntu and Debian, you can grub-install /dev/md0, and the partitions on both sda and sdb don't show up since they aren't really valid as it is the raid that is partitioned, not the individual disks.  You should also remember though, that raid != backup.  For periodic backups, it is best to use `tar` or `dump` ( they can do nightly incremental backups ) rather than imaging the whole drive.  Raid is not for backup, but to keep the system from going down, even for a minute, in the event of hardware failure.