# mdadm - Creating RAID1 on LiveUSB does not persist when re-booting

Tags: fedora, software-raid, cloning, raid1, mirror

I have three drives `sda`, `sdb`, and `sdc`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  2.7T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  500M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 97.7G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0  2.5T  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0  2.7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    1M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0  500M  0 part /boot
├─sdb3   8:19   0 97.7G  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   0  2.5T  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0  2.7T  0 disk /home
```

The first two I'm trying to aseemble into a RAID 1 array with the command:

`mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb -e 1.0`

using the 1.0 specification and (supposedly) writing the superblock at the end of the disk. However when I do this from a LiveUSB key, and reboot into `sda`, the array is gone. Actually if I reboot into the LiveUSB key the array is also not there, and `mdadm --assemble --scan -v` produces:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb4
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda4
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
```

But I just wrote the superblock! I even waited overnight for the array to assemble itself. And now it's like I never ran --create. I also read the [Linux RAID Wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#Saving_your_RAID_configuration), which suggests that I should save `/etc/mdadm.conf` (on Fedora), which I did with `mdadm --detail --scan > /mnt/etc/mdadm.conf` from the LiveUSB, after the create command, which produced:

```
$ cat /etc/mdadm.conf                                                                                                                                                                                              
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.0 name=manjaro:0 UUID=18fc0efb:50eb619e:621e8eee:8d1cd68d
```

What gives? Why is create not actually creating anything? Am I missing some options to commands? If you guys need more input from me please don't hesitate to ask for output of commands in the comments :)!

Thanks for your time and input!

**UPDATE 1**

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print free
[sudo] password for rivanov: 
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so    that will be used.
OK/Cancel? ok                                                             
Model: ATA WDC WD3003FZEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start        End          Size         File system  Name  Flags
        34s          2047s        2014s        Free Space
 1      2048s        4095s        2048s                              bios_grub
 2      4096s        1028095s     1024000s     ext4               raid
 3      1028096s     205828095s   204800000s   ext4               raid
 4      205828096s   5530423295s  5324595200s  ext4               raid
        5530423296s  5860533134s  330109839s   Free Space

$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda /dev/sdb
/dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

Comment: Use the 1.2 specification - that saves metadata about the RAID system, which the OS can then read (using `mdadm` itself, perhaps).

Comment: That will overwrite my partition table, and I've tried that option. I end up having to re clone my original hard drive with `dd` to `sda` in order to start from square one. See [my other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242005/how-do-i-clone-a-single-drive-onto-a-new-raid-1-array/242025?noredirect=1#comment414883_242025)

Comment: Are you sure about that? My partition table wasn't overwritten when I created a RAID0 (the existing partitions containing a Windows striped volume still work fine).

Comment: Oh, you're RAIDing the entire disk, not just one partition, but if that's the case, what's the problem with the partition table being lost?

Comment: Show `parted /dev/disk unit s print free` as well as `mdadm --examine /dev/sda /dev/sdb`. While it may be possible to make this work, it's better to use RAID on partitions rather than whole disk.

Comment: If you RAID the entire disk the partition table gets wiped.  Are you trying to turn two similarly-configured disks into a RAID 1?  Won't work.  If you want to do that, RAID 1 the two devices together and then use LVM to create partitions and filesystems. (edit) oh, and take a look at /proc/mdstat to check status after you run your create command.

Comment: OK, so it clashes with the GPT partition table which, also has a backup at the end. At the very least you'd need a metadata format that is 4K from the end (or further away) but it doesn't exist so - it shouldn't be done this way, you have to think of another setup.

Comment: I am trying to clone 1 disk, which I've done successfully, onto two new blank hard drives, which I want to make into a RAID 1 array. [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/733417/how-do-i-clone-a-single-drive-onto-a-new-raid-1-array) is my original post. `cat /proc/mdstat` will show the array being rebuilt as I stated I waited overnight for it to rebuild, and the in the morning it would not show up again after a reboot.

Comment: @frostschutz: couldn't I just use `gdisk` to delete the backup of the GTP table at the end? There are some [advanced](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html) options?

Comment: I do have one more identical blank hard drive laying about, could I just create a blank array on it and clone my original disk onto that array?

Comment: You'd have to parted the MD device instead of sda,sdb so the GPT backup will be at the end of the space provided by the RAID, thus before the RAID metadata at the end. Testing locally, `mdadm` (v3.3.4) seems to recognize such disks. But everytime you use a partitioning software on sda,sdb it will complain about GPT being the wrong size.

Comment: @frostschutz so you mean 1) Boot into LiveUSB 2) Create the array 3) `parted /dev/md0`? Wouldn't that erase my data? I know `mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0` will cuz I've tried that approach.